# Is there a way to short lots of repeated code in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, shortcut

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ### imports plotting
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Population:
    def __init__(self,name,population):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.conservative = self.population * 48/100
        self.labour = self.population * 30/100
        self.libDem = self.population * 12/100
        self.green = self.population * 5/100
        self.brexit = self.population * 3/100
        self.others = self.population * 2/100

    def distribution(self):
        print(self.conservative)
        print(self.labour)
        print(self.libDem)
        print(self.brexit)
        print(self.others)

    def rulingParty(self):
        parties = {"Conservative":self.conservative,"Labour":self.labour,"LibDem":self.libDem,"Green":self.green,"Brexit":self.brexit,"Other":self.others}
        return max(parties, key=parties.get)

    def addCon(self,amount, Lab=1/5,LD=1/5,GRN=1/5,BXT=1/5,Others=1/5):
        self.conservative += amount
        self.labour += -amount * Lab
        self.libDem += -amount * LD
        self.green += -amount * GRN
        self.brexit += -amount * BXT
        self.others += -amount * Others

    def addLab(self,amount, Con=1/5,LD=1/5,GRN=1/5,BXT=1/5,Others=1/5):
        self.labour += amount
        self.conservative += -amount * Con
        self.libDem += -amount * LD
        self.green += -amount * GRN
        self.brexit += -amount * BXT
        self.others += -amount * Others

    def addLD(self,amount, Con=1/5,Lab=1/5,GRN=1/5,BXT=1/5,Others=1/5):
        self.libDem += amount
        self.conservative += -amount * Con
        self.labour += -amount * Lab
        self.green += -amount * GRN
        self.brexit += -amount * BXT
        self.others += -amount * Others

    def addGRN(self,amount, Con=1/5,Lab=1/5,LD=1/5,BXT=1/5,Others=1/5):
        self.green += amount
        self.conservative += -amount * Con
        self.labour += -amount * Lab
        self.libDem += -amount * LD
        self.brexit += -amount * BXT
        self.others += -amount * Others

    def addBXT(self,amount, Con=1/5,Lab=1/5,LD=1/5,GRN=1/5,Others=1/5):
        self.brexit += amount
        self.conservative += -amount * Con
        self.labour += -amount * Lab
        self.libDem += -amount * LD
        self.green += -amount * GRN
        self.others += -amount * Others

    def addOthers(self,amount, Con=1/5,Lab=1/5,LD=1/5,GRN=1/5,BXT=1/5):
        self.others += amount
        self.conservative += -amount * Con
        self.labour += -amount * Lab
        self.libDem += -amount * LD
        self.green += -amount * GRN
        self.brexit += -amount * BXT

c = Population("UK",100000)
d = [c.conservative,c.labour,c.libDem,c.green,c.brexit,c.others]
while not c.rulingParty()=="Labour": 
    c.addCon(-1000)
    d = np.vstack((d,[c.conservative,c.labour,c.libDem,c.green,c.brexit,c.others]))


print(d)
print(np.shape(d)[0])
```

It should be noted that this is just an exercise I'm doing to improve my python skills and not a political simulation of any kind. My question is, is there any way to reduce the number of repeated lines amongst the addCon(), addLab() etc. functions, as they all have lots of the same code.

Any feedback would be appreciated
Yours,

Comment: You can create a dictionary with party names as keys and votes as values. The one and only add method gets the name as parameter. Then you iterate through the dict and add for given name, subtract for others (some more details are necessary yet).

Comment: Can you explain what the program does? Also this probably belongs on Code Review, not here.

Comment: In `addOthers`, why do you `+= -amount * _`? Why not `-= amount * _`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There absolutely is, but it involves a teeny bit of extra work.

First, I wouldn't have `libDem` and `conservative` as fields in the class. Instead, I'd have them be keys in a dictionary, and votes as values. Kinda like you do in the `ruling_party` method. But set the dictionary up in `__init__` instead, and then you can rewrite your methods.

In fact, you can consolidate them all into a single method:

```py
def add_party(self, party, amount, adjustment_factors):
    self.votes[party] += amount
    for other_party in self.votes:
        if other_party != party:
            factor = adjustment_factors.get(other_party, 1/5)
            self.votes[other_party] -= amount * factor
```

Comment: How would a create the dictionary with the values in the __init__?

Comment: `self.votes = {'Conservatives': 0, 'libDems': 0, 'Greens': 0, and so on and so forth`

Comment: Or I guess instead of 0 you'd put whatever initial value you want it to have

Comment: last question, sorry but I'm still pretty new to Python, what does the adjustments factors argument mean in the function. What should I use it for and how?

Comment: Well in your original methods you'd pass in the argument `GRN` for example and then reduce the Green's votes by `amount * GRN`. Now instead of having one parameter per party for this factor, (`GRN`, `Con` etc etc) we have just one dictionary `adjustment_factors`. Then we get the adjustment factor for a party out of that dictionary (with the `.get`) and we still use `1/5` as the default.

Though if the factor is always the same and always `1/5` then it doesn't need an argument at all anyway.